# rsElementTypeMismatch error When I Edit Subscription

Tags: ssrs-subscription

I updated the scheduling options in Step 7 of a data-driven subscription. The subscription did not execute at the specified time - no error message was  displayed. When I clicked "Edit", the following message appears:

"The value provided for the StartDateTime field is not valid for its type. It cannot be converted from a string value to the type that is required. (rsElementTypeMismatch)"

I have since run the subscription directly from its SQL Agent job. The dates and times in the job are valid.

Searching on "rsElementTypeMismatch" has not proven useful - I have reviewed most MSDN pages, MSSQLTIPS, etc. related to this error but they do not allow me to edit the actual subscription.

StartDateTime does not exist within the report, datasets or underlying SQL code. Nor can I find it as a column within the ReportServer tables.

Any suggestions on some useful info related to "rsElementTypeMismatch" or the error in general would be greatly appreciated.

Using SSRS 2008 R2.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem myself, and from the research I have done it appears to be a mismatch between the locality settings of the PC (Internet Explorer), from which the report is run from, the server on which SSRS is installed or the Database server that the data is pulled from.

In my instance a server upgrade had been carried out and one server had a locality set as English (Which is American English), and the remainder where British English.

This error is to do with the way each locality deals with dates. America language shows dates as MM/DD/YYYY, while British Language shows dates as DD/MM/YYYY.

Applications wont allow for example the 30th day to be a month, so it throws it out.

I was unable to edit the subscription and had to recreate it from scratch.

The StartDateTime Field you are receiving the error on, may be on the actual report or within a parameter on the report.